# Keep first 20 nucleotides of sequences using R

Tags: r, scrnaseq, bioconductor, crispr

I have an Excel sheet from the CRISPR library where I have sequences of gRNAs (with 30 nucleotides) in a column and I only need to keep the first 20 nucleotides for those gRNAs and delete the rest nucleotides. The column has 1000 rows that have 30 nucleotide gRNA sequences. How can I delete extra nucleotides using R

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to "read" your data. There are packages that can read Excel files directly but I would save the data as csv first and then use `read.csv()`. The following would create a new column with your desired output:

```
data_frame$new_col <- substring(data_frame$col_with_seqs, 1, 20)
```

Alternatively you can just use Excel's `LEFT()` since your data is already in Excel:

```
=LEFT(A1, 20)
```